# Is it safe to truncate the catalog_category_product_index table?

Tags: database, performance, indexing

That is, will it be re-indexed from scratch?

I can not find it in the list of tables that are safe to truncate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205714/list-of-tables-to-safely-truncate-in-magento).

I'm on Magento 1.4.1, although this should apply to other versions as well, provided the index does still exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`catalog_category_product_index` contains the index which connects products and categories. This table can be truncated without problems, because the indexer rebuilds it, correct.

The table `catalogindex_price` doesn't exist in my EE 1.12.1 which I am looking at the moment, so no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
-- Logs
TRUNCATE adminnotification_inbox;
TRUNCATE report_viewed_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_compared_product_index;
TRUNCATE report_event;
TRUNCATE catalog_compare_item;
TRUNCATE customer_log;
TRUNCATE mageplaza_smtp_log;
TRUNCATE mst_search_report_log;
TRUNCATE amasty_audit_log;
TRUNCATE oauth_token_request_log;
TRUNCATE amasty_audit_log_details;
TRUNCATE captcha_log;
TRUNCATE release_notification_viewer_log;
TRUNCATE sendfriend_log;
-- Url
TRUNCATE url_rewrite;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_url_rewrite_product_category;
-- Index
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_category_product_index;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_attribute_cl;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalogrule_product_cl;
TRUNCATE TABLE catalog_product_price_cl;
TRUNCATE TABLE cataloginventory_stock_cl;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```