# Is it safe to truncate the catalogindex_* tables?

Tags: database, performance, indexing, reindex

My Magento installation (1.4.1) contains the following tables:

```
catalogindex_price
catalogindex_minimal_price
catalogindex_eav
catalogindex_aggregation
catalogindex_aggregation_tag
catalogindex_aggregation_to_tag
```

Since there is an *index* in their name, will they be rebuilt by a re-index, that is, may I safely truncate them?

I can not find any of them in the list of tables that are safe to truncate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205714/list-of-tables-to-safely-truncate-in-magento).

I'm on Magento 1.4.1, although this might apply to other versions as well, provided these tables exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to truncate the catalog\_category\_product\_index table?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17077/is-it-safe-to-truncate-the-catalog-category-product-index-table)

Comment: Nope, this refers to a differet set of tables which wasn't answered in the question above.

Comment: Damn. Sorry. I promise to read more carefully next time. I will retract my close vote.

Comment: @workflow did you ever end up doing this? If so did it work?

Comment: @david-manners We did truncate the catalogindex_price table only, as it was somewhat larger - the others are negligible in size. No adverse effects so far, after running in production for almost a month.
Since Magento hasn't re-populated it, I'm guessing these are indeed legacy tables leftover after an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the history of `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml` it turns out that:

- catalogindex_price was removed in 1.4
- catalogindex_minimal_price is still used as of 1.9
- catalogindex_eav was removed in 1.4
- catalogindex_aggregation is still used as of 1.9
- catalogindex_aggregation_tag is still used as of 1.9
- catalogindex_aggregation_to_tag is still used as of 1.9

That being said, it's safe to **DROP** `catalogindex_price` and `catalogindex_eav` and safe to **TRUNCATE** the others if you rebuild the index afterwards. But note that the shop might behave weird until the reindex process finished so you might want to put it into maintenance mode. And as always, don't forget to make backups.

#### Sources

- http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.3/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml
- http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.4/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml
- http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogIndex/etc/config.xml